# How I can leave the counter code?

Tags: java, android, counter

**My Problem:**
I don't know, how I can leave my counter-code (CountDownTimer), IF the user click the imageButton within the counter of 2 seconds

**My Code:**

```
final ImageButton avatarScroll = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAvatarback);

avatarScroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ursprungAvatar = !ursprungAvatar;
            if(ursprungAvatar) {
                //image change with arrow
                ImageButton avatarScroll = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAvatarback);
                avatarScroll.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatarback_pfeil);
                new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //image change without arrow
                        ImageButton avatarScroll = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAvatarback);
                        avatarScroll.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatarback);
                        ursprungAvatar = !ursprungAvatar;
                    }
                }.start();

            } else {
                //image change without arrow
                ImageButton avatarScroll_ursprung = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAvatarback);
                avatarScroll_ursprung.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatarback);
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the intended behavour? On the first click, the timer is started, on the second click, it should be stopped? Based on this, you only need to terminate the timer in the else case.

Comment: If you mean by "leave" you want to stop it, then you have to make a global CountDownTimer object and call cancel if the timer runs...

Comment: This is too vague. Edit with a more proper description of what you want to do.

Comment: ...and by inspecting your code, why you are creating the button every time? Just make one global button and change it´s background when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the behavour right, all you need to do, is adding `timer.cancel()` in the else case and keep a reference to the created timer  (eg make it a field).